# Which game is this Link from?

Tags: game-identification, legend-of-zelda-series

Despite my hours of scouring, I have been unable to identify this Link specifically (as there are 12 different Links that appear in 20 games, not including animations):

[image: The Missing Link?]

Which game/movie/animation is this specific gif from? (BONUS: Which Hero is this?)

I wanted to say this was either the Hero of Skies or Link from Hyrule Warriors, but not sure.

Comment: Where did you find this gif?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This gif comes from the fan-made short "Racing for Rupees" on Youtube:

The moment appears around the [3:30](https://youtu.be/it2sk2nzbnY?t=207) mark.

Answer (score 26):

Given that the gif only shows a very restricted shot of Link, it's hard to say for certain, but I believe this is the [Link from Hyrule Warriors](https://zelda-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Link_(Hyrule_Warriors)), based on the graphics and art style.

As you can see below, he has the same haircut, the same chain mail armor, and the same shirt beneath the armor. Only the scarf is different. Maybe he's just not currently wearing his scarf in the gif?

[image: Hyrule Warriors Link]

Comment: Ahhh, thank you so much! I had a hunch this was the one; the gold lining is probably the most distinct giveaway, as none of the others have it.

Comment: Just to note: The gif is from an animation in another answer. That animation has no affiliation to Nintendo. So its probably not exactly the model from one particular Zelda game, but I does seem to be a model that is lossely based on the one from Hyrule Warriors.

Comment: The animation was actually released well before Hyrule Warriors, but it's funny how similar the models are.